# What load can i connect if data sheet is missing output voltage

Tags: dc-dc-converter, power-electronics, datasheet

I am looking at a DC to DC converter data sheet that has an input voltage of 0V-100V. The datasheet only mentions a max output current of 4 amps. Is it safe to assume I can place a load of any voltage as long as it is lower than my input voltage, and draws less than 4 amps?

I have attached the data sheet for reference. [Converter Data Sheet](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bel-Power-Solutions/FC100V5A-G?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvGsmoEFRKS8PLO8c8JSEILV%252bWL1ao3dso%3D)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: This specific DC to DC converter doesn't have output voltage specified. Either choose another part or contact the manufacturer for that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking at a DC to DC converter data sheet that has an input voltage of 0V-100V.

[image]

*Figure 1. From the datasheet.*

No you're not. That's in input filter for a DC-DC converter. From the datasheet:

> Power-One offers a complete range of input filters to
>   help control EMI in board-level DC-DC converter
>   applications.

The **voltage rating** will tell you the maximum voltage that the filter can withstand between positive and negative lines.

The **current rating** is the maximum current that the device can handle *through* the filter.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize this. I thought it was a converter based off the description "Isolated DC/DC Converters 0-100Vin 5A 1500VDC Isolation".